# Need help in WildcardFileFilter in java

Tags: java

I have to separate out those files from a folder which matches one of the given pattern. I have an array of strings which contains these patterns.
 And I am passing this array as argument into WildCardFilter so that I can separate out thse files which matches the given pattern in the array. My code is given below.

```
String pat1="DailyExistingBusinessReport_*";
String pat2="*DailyNewExistingBusinessReport_.csv";
String pat3="*_EOD_PNL_Explained.*";
String pat4="ABC*XYZ.csv";
String str[]=new String[]{pat1,pat2,pat3,pat4};
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(str);
File dir = new File("\\C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\Myfiles");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);

for(File f :files){
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

This prints out the name of files which matches the patterns given in array. But now my requirement is that alongwith each file name, I want the exact name of pattern to which this file matched. Any idea what code should I add further to get pattern name alongwith file name.

Comment: Please format your code. The help center can show you how.

Comment: What's WildcardFileFilter? It's not in the standard API.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the API and don't see the way to do that with the `FileFilter`. 
I suggest creating a list of filters and apply them one by one:

```
List<FileFilter> filters = new ArrayList<FileFilter>();
filters.add(new WildCardFileFilter("DailyExistingBusinessReport_*");
filters.add(new WildCardFileFilter("*DailyNewExistingBusinessReport_.csv");
filters.add(new WildCardFileFilter("*_EOD_PNL_Explained.*");
filters.add(new WildCardFileFilter("ABC*XYZ.csv");

File dir = new File("\\C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\Myfiles");
Map<FileFilter, List<File>> filemap = new HashMap<FileFilter, List<File>>();

for (File file: dir.listFiles()){
    for(FileFilter filter: filters){
         if(filter.accept(file)){
             if(!filemap.containsKey(filter)){
                 filemap.put(filter, new ArrayList<File>());
             }
             filemap.get(filter).add(file);
         }
    }
}
```

After that, you should have a map which contain filters and lists of files for which the filter apply. 
I don't have IDE by hand, so there may be some small mistakes.

Comment: I exactly did the same which you have written but it involves two for loops and number of files are large. This will make program inefficient.

Comment: I don't think you can find much more efficient way than this. You iterate over the files only once and to be consistent you have to check all the filters for each file(some files may be applied to multiple filters). Try to check the sources for ```File.listFiles(FileFilter filter)```, maybe I'm wrong. btw thanks Boann for fixes :)